# Flagging a question that is "probably" off topic

Tags: discussion, flagging

I was wondering what the general policy is regarding flagging a question that you are fairly sure is off-topic or not in any way related to SharePoint? The key here is a lack of absolute certainty, most often due to a lack of comprehension. I sometimes see questions that look like they have nothing to do with SharePoint and are probably posted in the wrong place, but since I am not all-knowing and I'm not big into programming I can't be absolutely certain. In that instance, should the post be called out via comment or flag, or should I just give it the benefit of the doubt and leave it alone?

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead and flag it, if 4 other users feel the same way, it will be closed as off topic. If a moderator sees the flag and agrees before 4 other non-moderators flag it, it will be closed as well.